# Arc suppression on electromagnet circuit

Tags: snubber, arc

I have an application where an aluminum arm is contacting a steel spring and there is a lot of arcing. The contact energizes a 12v electromagnet with a 47ohm coil drawing 250mA and a 4700uF cap to extend the magnet's pull after contact is broken. I have tried several combinations of resistors and caps across the contact but nothing works. I am also having trouble calculating the correct values using C. C. Bates' formula. Can anyone help?

[image: Antonio51 - Here's a schematic:]

Comment: Maybe the problem is mechanical and you need to take care that the spring doesn't touch the arm (e.g. some isolation)?

Comment: Can you make a little picture and schematic?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The arm touching the spring IS the contact. When the arm hits the spring the electromagnet pulls the arm back over and over again.
I've added a schematic to my post.

Comment: Ok ... it is as an old electromagnetic "buzzer"?

Comment: Not a buzzer but the same principle, just think of an regular switch turning on a magnet and a capacitor.

Comment: Just put a free-wheeling diode?

Comment: @Antonio51 Please explain how I would do that.

Comment: Have you tried adding a series resistance with the cap, only? It looks like when it's disharged, you're shorting out the + and -, until it charges. If you add a series resistance (a few Ohms / W power rating) it should limit the current, but it will cause a small voltage drop when it will try to "keep alive" the relay.

Comment: I think ... Not usable here. Because of the capacitor. I think at an old circuit, not very used. Calculate Lcoil/Rcoil = Constant. Then insert with C another resistor so that Rs*C is same Constant. I make a simulation to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prevent the arcing when turning off you can use a [flyback diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode).
The current in the inductor will continue to flow until the magnetic field has decayed.
*Without* flyback diode there is only a very high resistance path (air) for this current to flow. Ohms law than takes point and makes the voltage up to arcing high.
*With* flyback diode this current can loop through the diode resulting in a voltage not higher than -Vf. *(negative forward voltage)*

This does increase the time it takes for the magnetic field to decay.
If you want quickest decay of the magnetic field you can take the energy out by using an resistor in series with the diode. Pick a resistance that does not exceed your maximum voltage at nominal coil current.

[image: schematic]

### <sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPQS27.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To prevent contact welding when turning on you can use an inrush current limiter circuit. Or perhaps something as simple an a NTC suffices. For example the circuit within the dashed box above.
Note that you would need the diode to only limit the capacitor inrush, and not limit discharge of the capacitor or immediate actuation of the coil.

Comment: Circuitlab circuits are, unfortunately, automatically scaled down to fit the width of the page horizontally, but not vertically. You can make the circuit smaller by adding something off to the side, like a wire not connected to anything or something, so that it'll be wider than it is tall and get scaled down.

Comment: @Hearth Yeah, I've added some more stuff, a bit better now.

Comment: @Jeroen3 - now if you could just give me the values of C1 and R1 that would be great!

Comment: @GLF555 C1 and R1 are up to you. High C1 means long hold time. High R1 means it takes longer for the cap to charge. You probably want R1 to be rated such that the total current trough the switch does not exceed it's rating. For the Diodes you want the lowest Vf at 250mA with sufficient rated power.

Comment: Sorry, I have really limited electrical knowledge so it is difficult for me to determine the values of R1 and C1. The charge time (instant?) and hold time created by the bare 4700 uF cap I am using now is perfect so I would like to keep it the same. The "switch" is just two metal pieces touching so there is no rating. As for the diodes I have a bunch of IN4001s - would they work?

Comment: @Jeroen3 Sorry, forgot to tag you on my last comment.

Comment: @GLF555 A 100 Ohm resistor will put you at around 1.5 seconds [charge time](https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-time-constant) with a maximum current of 120mA. The 1N4001 can work in principle, you can get better ones if you know what to look for.

Comment: @jeroen3 I need the 4700uF cap to charge faster and the current to the coil to be the full 250mA. But still with no arcing.

Comment: @Jeroen3 Your solution reduced the arcing significantly, but on the very first contact there is still occasionally a spark. R1 of 100 ohms reduced the action of the cap/magnet too much. Many lower R values worked better than 100 ohms and seemed to be the same so I just randomly chose 10 ohms. What effect does a lower R value have?